# How to let a stack store coordinates on a board

Tags: c#

I was writing a stack that can store row and column which a user inputs through textboxes on windows forms. However when I use the code I added when you press a button it doesn't work.

```
Stack mystack = new Stack();
Stack.Push(Row,Column);
```

The error I get is "No overload for method push takes 2 arguments". How can I correct my code so it adds the row and column to the stack everytime the user presses the button.

Comment: You can define a class with those two fields and use a Stack of that type i.e. Stack<YourClass> and then push objects onto the stack. Another way is to use a stack of tuples and push like `stack.Push((Row,Column))`

Answer (score 0):

A `Stack` stores a list of objects, not a list of pairs of objects. You can only add one object at a time. If you want to store a row and column as a single value then you need to use a type that can store those two values. You could define your own type but you may as well just use the existing `Point` type. You should also use a generic `Stack<T>`, just as you would use a `List<T>` rather than an `ArrayList`.

```cs
var points = new Stack<Point>();

points.Push(new Point(column, row));
```

Note the order of the `column` and `row` values, because the first value should be the `X` (horizontal) value and the second should be the `Y` (vertical) value.

When you `Pop`, you'll get a `Point` value and you can then get the `X` and `Y` values from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `class called coordinate` as follows:

```
    public class coordinate 
    { 
        public coordinate(double _x, double _y)
        {
            this.x = _x;
            this.y = _y;
        }
        public double x; 
        public double y; 
    }
```

And define the stack as below:

```
     Stack<coordinate> mystack = new Stack<coordinate>();
     mystack.Push( new coordinate(1,1));
```

Comment: If I had a class called Board and it had row and column in it could I use this same method.

Comment: @IntahimAhmed Yes, you can change the name of the class to `Board` and edit the variable `x and y` to `Row and Column`

Comment: Ok so I tried to do it but the problem is the row and column is put through a textbox so when I try to do something like public int row = Row; it says can't convert text to int.

Comment: you can use row = double.Parse(textBox.Text) ;